# git push currently stuck at 70%

Tags: git, github, netlify

I am trying to push to my repo, I believe the reason the git push is taking forever is due to some decently large video files.  I am using continuous deployment with netlify which takes my github repo and points it to my netlify domain, if I were to git ignore these files would they even be present on my deployed site?? very unsure of what to do at this point.

Comment: You should host the large media files outside of your code repository.

Comment: should I use like an S3 bucket or something along those lines? @sdgluck

Comment: Yeah that is certainly one way that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the [git LFS implementation](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations) in order to chose an external backend for your large video files.

For example, [`jasonwhite/rudolfs`](https://github.com/jasonwhite/rudolfs), a high-performance, caching Git LFS server with an AWS S3 back-end.

[Netlify Large Media uses Git LFS](http://A%20high-performance,%20caching%20Git%20LFS%20server%20with%20an%20AWS%20S3%20back-end.), but with some [requirements and limitations](https://docs.netlify.com/large-media/requirements-and-limitations/).